# How do I speed up this specific for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I've looked at other threads and tried to apply it to my code but have had no luck.

```
CDR3_post_challenge_unique_clonecount$participant_per_cdr3aa <- as.numeric(CDR3_post_challenge_unique_clonecount$cdr3aa)
participant_list <- unique(CDR3_post_challenge_unique_clonecount$cdr3aa)
for (c in participant_list)
{
  CDR3_post_challenge_unique_clonecount$participant_per_cdr3aa[CDR3_post_challenge_unique_clonecount$cdr3aa == c] <- length(unique(CDR3_post_challenge_unique_clonecount$PartID[CDR3_post_challenge_unique_clonecount$cdr3aa == c]))
}
```

Here is a bit of the dataframe:

```
cdr3aa              clonecount  PartID
CAAGRAARGGSVPHWFDPF 1           S-1
CAALADSGSQTDAFDIA   1           S-1
CAFHAAYGSQHGLDVW    1           S-1
CAGGLAWLVDDW        1           S-1
CAGRWFFPW           1           S-1
CAGVKNGRGMDVW       1           S-1
```

Comment: Hi! Can you provide the sample of your data frame and participant_list with ```dput ()``` because, without that, it is hard to understand what we are dealing with. Read more about making reproducible examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can replace the `for` loop with

```r
CDR3_post_challenge_unique_clonecount$per3 <-
  as.integer(
    ave(CDR3_post_challenge_unique_clonecount$PartID,
        CDR3_post_challenge_unique_clonecount$cdr3aa,
        FUN = function(z) length(unique(z)))
  )
```

I'll demonstrate with `mtcars`, using the follow analogs:

- `mtcars` --> `CDR3_post_challenge_unique_clonecount`
- `cyl` --> `cdr3aa`, the categorical variable in which we want to count `PartID`
- `drat` --> `PartID`, the thing we want to count (uniquely) within each `cdr3aa`

```r
mtcars$drat_per_cyl <- ave(mtcars$drat, mtcars$cyl, FUN = function(z) length(unique(z)))
mtcars
#                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb drat_per_cyl
# Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4            5
# Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4            5
# Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1           10
# Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1            5
# Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2           11
# Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1            5
# Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4           11
# Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2           10
# Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2           10
# Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4            5
# Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4            5
# Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3           11
# Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3           11
# Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3           11
# Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4           11
# Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4           11
# Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4           11
# Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1           10
# Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2           10
# Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1           10
# Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1           10
# Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2           11
# AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2           11
# Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4           11
# Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2           11
# Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1           10
# Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2           10
# Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2           10
# Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4           11
# Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6            5
# Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8           11
# Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2           10
```

Notes:

- `ave` is a *little* brain-dead in that the class of the return value is *always* the same as the class of the first argument. This means that one cannot count unique `"character"` and expect to get an integer, it is instead returned as a string. It's because of this that I wrap `ave` in `as.integer(.)`.
- `ave` returns a vector the same length as the input, with values corresponding 1-for-1 (meaning the order is relevant and preserved). In my example of `mtcars`, this means that it is effectively doing something like this:

  ```r
  ind4 <- which(mtcars$cyl == 4L)
  ind4
  #  [1]  3  8  9 18 19 20 21 26 27 28 32
  length(unique(mtcars$drat[ind4]))
  # [1] 10
  ind6 <- which(mtcars$cyl == 6L)
  ind6
  # [1]  1  2  4  6 10 11 30
  length(unique(mtcars$drat[ind6]))
  # [1] 5
  ### ...
  ```

  but it will place the return value `10` in the `ind4` positions of the return value. For example, because of my `ind6`, the return value will start with

  ```r
  c(5, 5, .., 5, .., 5, .., .., .., 5, 5, .., .....)
  ```

  Because of `ind4`, it will contain

  ```r
  c(.., .., 10, .., .., .., .., 10, 10, .....)
  ```

  (And same for `cyl==8L`.)

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but end up getting an output of NA for each row.

Comment: That's very interesting.

Comment: I get this warning: ```50: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1L) : invalid factor level, NA generated```

Comment: Okay. While I completely understand *"I am not allowed to"* share sample data, do you understand how there is very little I can do without something reproducible? Either find a way to anonymize your data (no need to make it reversible, you just need to de-identity it perhaps) or find a way to produce similar-enough (i.e., *representative*) fake sample data that we can use. Good luck.

Comment: I've added a sample to the post

Comment: Good start, but ... it doesn't error, and it returns all `1`s.